# Python http-request source missing JavaScript

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, cas

I am attempting to login to my [school's meal system](https://services.jsatech.com/index.php?cid=52) using Python and the `requests` library. I am able to successfully login and get the `CASTGC` cookie. After authenticating to CAS, I am redirected to a loading page which `python` outputs as:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
window.location.href='/login.php?cid=52&fullscreen=1&wason=';
</script>
```

However, when I look at the loading page source visually using chrome dev tools, I see the following (I have omitted irrelevant portions of this source):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function pollTaskmaster() {
        attempts++;
        var url = "login-check.php?skey=92d82c6ad669e17c63fb860981e19229"; 
        validate(url);
}

    function validate(url) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        isIE = true;
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = processPollRequest;
    req.send(null);
}

    function processPollRequest() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                var message = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("message")[0];
            if (!message) {
          window.location.href='login.php?cid=52&';
          return;
        }
        var remotestatus = message.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        if (remotestatus == 1 )
           window.location.href='index.php?cid=52&';
        if (remotestatus == -1 )
           window.location.href='login.php?cid=52&';
    } else {
        window.status = "No Update ";
    }
        window.status = "Processing request...";    
        setTimeout("pollTaskmaster()", 5000);
    }
}

function gotobadpage() {
  window.location.href='login.php?cid=52&';
}
```

In order to continue into the actual meal system, I need an `skey` which is present in javascript code of the page source (in the `pollTaskmaster` function) when I physically download and examine it, but is missing from python's response.

I am not sure why this is the case. How would I go about accessing this JavaScript source in order to actually extract this parameter? I am currently just examining the `response.text` received after sending a post request to the CAS authentication system and successfully logging in.

> Additionally, I know this can be done because in [this GitHub project](https://github.com/blakemotl/PolyDiningProject/blob/master/polydining/src/main/java/com/themotlcode/polydining/models/DataCollector.java), the author comments `/* follow redirects to meal plan loading page and get skey from the jscript in the page. */`, referring to the same meal plan loading page that I am currently stuck on.

Comment: have you searched the javascript source files?

Comment: Selenium may be a good option for this task (headless browsing).

Comment: @SamCreamer I was hoping to be able to do this using just python requests but selenium is my backup plan

Comment: Any time I've had to get real browser output, I've had a lot more luck with Selenium. I think that a lot of web servers will not a give a full JavaScript response to a client like `requests`. It could depend on the site and scenario though. You can also manually change the headers and try for different outcomes.

Comment: @SamCreamer So I just tried with `selenium` and I am able to see the full JavaScript source with it. However, my end goal is to put this functionality in a `flask` api so that I can query it and have the scraping done in the backend so I'm not sure if it is feasible to use selenium for this

Comment: @Markoe7 it's still feasible! I've used Selenium for similar programs.